# How to send several embeds in one message?

Tags: embed, discord.js

I was looking at discord.js documentation and I saw this:

> .embeds
> A list of embeds in the message - e.g. YouTube Player
> Type: Array

"A list" :O ?
That mean it is possible to have several embeds in one message.
I have been looking for a way to do this, but I didn't find anything (I know there is another post on stack overflow about that, but it is inactive and unawsnered).

I took an old code `channel.send(this.embed());` and tried to edit it so it send two embeds instead of just one.
`this.embed()` runs.

```js
{ 
    var builder = new Discord.RichEmbed();
    builder.setTitle(...);
    ...
    return builder
}
```

First attempt was:

```js
channel.send(this.embed(), this.embed());
```

- send **[object Object]** then the second embed*

```js
channel.send("", this.embed(), this.embed());
```

- send the first embed*

Then I looked at the doc more about .send:

> .send([content] , [options])
> Send a message to this channel.
>
> blabla
>
> Example 4

```js
// Send an embed with a local image inside
channel.send('This is an embed', {
    embed: {
        thumbnail: {
            url: 'attachment://file.jpg'
        }
    },
    files: [{
        attachment: 'entire/path/to/file.jpg',
        name: 'file.jpg'
    }]
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
```

So I used that example and try to reproduce it for my case.
I tried a lot of differents syntax, and I won't post all the variations ^^'
But I want to show you these two :

```js
channel.send("", {
    {embed:this.embed(petit)},
    {embed:this.embed(petit)}
});
```

- SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```js
channel.send("", {
    embed: [{this.embed(petit), this.embed(petit)}]
});
```

- SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

etc...

I feel like I get closer to the solution with the last attempts but I'm still missing something.

I really want to have all my embeds in *one* message, I know I can send them one by one but I don't want that :)
Also is there a maximum amount of embeds in a message ?

Thanks for reading, I hope I didn't made that much typos ^^

Nalfarvi

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiples embedded messages with this syntax:

```js
channel.send({
    embed: {
        // Your embedded message's content
    },
    embed: {
        // Your second embedded message's content
    }
})
```

Comment: Do you need to use 
`embed: {
>    thumbnail: {
>         url: 'attachment://file.jpg'
>      }
>   }`

or can you still use RichEmbed ?